# Use RapidJson in Cocos2dx, it crash in Accept(writer) in IOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, rapidjson

I use Cocos2dx 3.9; and use rapidjson to convert CCDictionary to string; I find it will crash in value->Accept(wirter) in Real machine; but work will in Simulator.

```
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
value->Accept(writer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my error, I use:

```
rapidjson::Value *value = KSCCJsonRapid::jsonValueFromDictionary(dic);
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
value->Accept(writer);
std::string jsonString = buffer.GetString();
```

but in

```
static rapidjson::Value* jsonValueFromDictionary(cocos2d::CCDictionary *dic, rapidjson::Document *document = NULL);
```

, I create a new document, and delete it; in Real machine, the memory is limit; so the value is invalid.
it can be corrected by :

```
rapidjson::Document *document = new Document();
rapidjson::Value *value = KSCCJsonRapid::jsonValueFromDictionary(dic, document);
rapidjson::StringBuffer buffer;
rapidjson::Writer<rapidjson::StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
value->Accept(writer);
std::string jsonString = buffer.GetString();
delete value;
delete document;
```